# How to select cells NOT containing a certain word

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel table, in which some of the cells of the C column contain the word "Rinse" (the other cells have various other contents).

Using VBA code, here's how I would select all rows containing the word "Rinse" in the C column - this code works fine.

```
For i = 3 To 300
    If Cells(i, 3).Value = "Rinse" Then
        Rows(i).Select
        Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
    End If
Next
```

However, I want to do exactly the opposite, namely to **select all rows NOT containing the word "Rinse" in the C column**. I've tried the following, but it doesn't work.

```
For i = 3 To 300
    If Cells(i, 3).Value = Not "Rinse" Then
        Rows(i).Select
        Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
    End If
Next
```

How do I get this done?

Comment: NB: Yes, after selecting I remove the formatting of the selected cells - forgot to mention that.

Comment: Use `If Cells(i, 3).Value <> "Rinse" Then`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Instr` function, like this:

```
If Instr(Cells(i, 3).Value, "Rinse") = 0 Then
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Like` operator can be useful here:

```
If Not Cells(i, 3).Value Like "*Rinse*" Then
```

If "Rinse" can be found anywhere in your cell value

Answer (score 2):

Change this line of your code ( <> not equals to)

```
 If Cells(i, 3).Value <> "Rinse" Then
```

Answer (score 2):

You could filter out the Rinse values and then select the visible cells.
Could be quicker than looking at each individual cell.

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim lRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(lRow, 3))
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*Rinse*"
            'Can replace Select in next row with .FormatConditions.Delete
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
        End With
        .ShowAllData
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of this code is in its speed. Acceleration is achieved by referencing the sheet only once for every row and only once for the result, and by formatting only the used range columns instead of the entire rows.

```
Private Sub SelectNonContiguousRange()

    Dim RngAddress() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim R As Long

    ReDim RngAddress(300)                   ' this number should be
    With ActiveSheet
        For R = 3 To 300                    ' equal to this number
            ' use = (equal) or <> (unequal) as required:
            If .Cells(R, "C").Value <> "Rinse" Then
'            If .Cells(R, "C").Value = "Rinse" Then
                RngAddress(i) = .Range(.Cells(R, "A"), _
                                       .Cells(R, .UsedRange.Columns.Count)).Address
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next R
        ReDim Preserve RngAddress(i - 1)
        .Range(Join(RngAddress, ",")).FormatConditions.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

BTW, you can use a variation of this code to select multiple rows simultaneously (like you can do with Ctl+Click), for example all rows containing the word "Rinse".

Answer (score 0):

@Renee - Change the if condition line as shown below.

```
For i = 3 To 300
    If Cells(i, 3).Value <> "Rinse" Then
        Rows(i).Select
        Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
    End If
Next
```